# Where should scripts go MVC4 / Razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I just recently started using MVC4 & Razor. Previously, there were sections in each view page for `ScriptContent`, `MainContent`, etc.

While before I would always put the javascript/jquery I needed in the Script area, now I don't know how I should handle it. Is there a common practice or a specific place this should go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer:

1. *Bundles* are rendered with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/<name>")` and by default are registered in `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles` method. This is how you'd normally include jQuery and other frameworks and libraries. There's more information [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).
2. *Sections* are still there if you need them and are used much [like in ASP.NET MVC3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx).

Comment: bundles are awesome if you write good javascript. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: What about my own custom scripts for page interactivity?

Comment: @DoctorOreo I'd go with bundles for custom scripts too since you get minification for free and syntax is a bit simpler.